# How to get an array of counts of specific objects in an existing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar',
    ...
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar',
    ...
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'z',
    foo: 'bar',
    ...
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar',
    ...
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar',
    ...
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'z',
    foo: 'bar',
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

And another array that has the values of `importantKey`:

```
keysArray = [x, y, z]
```

How would I get an array with values that are counts of all the objects that have each `importantKey` in the same order as `keysArray`? So the final result would be:

```
[ numberOfObjectsWithKeyX, numberOfObjectsWithKeyY, numberOfObjectsWithKeyZ ]
```

For this example, the result would be:

```
[2, 2, 2]
```

Also `keysArray` is dynamically generated, so `x`, `y`, and `z` cannot be hard-coded.

Comment: please add the wanted result of the example.

Comment: Could the result be an object not an array?

Comment: @Matt, kindly have a look at my easy solution using `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
keysArray.map(key => values.filter(v => v.importantKey === key).length);
```

Basically, you call `map()` on the `keysArray` which will create a parallel array to it with whatever values `map()` spits out.

For that value, you just call `values.filter()` and filter out only the things that have the appropriate key, then just check the length to get the count.

```js
const values = [
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'z',
    foo: 'bar'
  }
];

const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const result = keys.map(key => values.filter(v => v.importantKey === key).length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is the exact implementation I already have and I'm getting and array with the correct number of elements, but they are all `undefined` instead of the number. The problem must have something to do with the fact that `keys` and `values` are both being dynamically created by rxjs observables.

Thanks anyway. At least I know that this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Array `map` function and then `filter` method.

`map` function transforms the array into another array. 
`filter` function allows to filter the array with a specified predicate. In this case, you need to compare the `importantKey` value.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'z',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'y',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'z',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  },
  {
    importantKey: 'x',
    foo: 'bar',
    
  }
 
];

var keysArray = ['x', 'y', 'z']
console.log(keysArray.map(a => arr1.filter(b=>b.importantKey == a).length));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table as reference to the indices for the result array.

This proposal uses a slingle loop for iterating the data.

```js
var data = [{ importantKey: 'x', foo: 'bar' }, { importantKey: 'y', foo: 'bar' }, { importantKey: 'z', foo: 'bar' }, { importantKey: 'x', foo: 'bar' }, { importantKey: 'y', foo: 'bar' }, { importantKey: 'z', foo: 'bar' }],
    keysArray = ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = keysArray.map(function (k, i) { hash[k] = i; return 0; });

data.forEach(function (o) {
    result[hash[o.importantKey]]++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to understand solution.

1. Read the `data`
2. Insert into `map`
3. Iterate through `map`
4. Insert into array `k` in order of `[x,y,z]`

```js
var data = 
[
  {importantKey: 'z', foo: 'bar' },
  {importantKey: 'y', foo: 'bar' },
  {importantKey: 'z', foo: 'bar' },
  {importantKey: 'x', foo: 'bar' },
  {importantKey: 'y', foo: 'bar' },
  { importantKey: 'z', foo: 'bar' },
]

document.write(JSON.stringify(data) + "<br>");

const map = {};
for (i in data)
{
  const key = data[i].importantKey;
  map[key] = (map[key] || 0) + 1;
  document.write(key); // zyzxyz
}
document.write("<br>map = " + JSON.stringify(map)); // {"z":3,"y":2,"x":1}

const k = [];
for(i in map) {
  //k.push(map[i]);
  k.splice(map[i] - 'x', 0, map[i]);
}
document.write("<br>k = " + JSON.stringify(k)); // [1,2,3]
```